# “parabéns pra você X parabéns a você

Tags: português-brasileiro, preposições, uso-mais-comum

Qual é a diferença entre **parabéns a você** e **parabéns para você**? Será que a segunda frase está errada e a primeira certa? Isso foi o que descobri procurando na internet. Se sim, por que as pessoas sempre falam **parabéns para você**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não vejo diferença alguma.  Gramaticalmente, ambas as formas estão corretas e são de uso corrente em pt-BR. A canção "Happy Birthday to You" foi traduzida para o Portugués como **"Parabéns pra você"** e, talvez por esse motivo a preposição "para" tem sido muito usada. Eu, pessoalmente, só uso "pra" na canção, e **uso "parabéns a" em quase todas as outras situações.**

- "Parabéns a todos que deixaram de lado seus interesses pessoais e..."
- "Parabéns àqueles que conseguiram nota máxima na prova."
- "Meus parabéns pelo seu aniversário."
- "Quero parabenizá-lo por ter feito..."

Comment: Em pt-PT usamos "Parabéns a você" na canção.